# How to use multiple java.net.CookieHandler in one application?

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection, cookiemanager

I was just wondering if it is possible to use multiple `java.net.CookieHandler` in one application. The only way to use a `CookieHandler`, I found, is by using the following:

```
public static void setDefault(CookieHandler cHandler)
```

I my case, I want to login multiple times into the same site and so I need more then one `CookieHandler`.

1. Do I understand this right?
2. Is there a way to use a `CookieHandler` not on a global level?

Unfortunately `HttpURLConnection` doesn't provide such a function like `.useCookieHandler(cHandler)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting up a default `CookieHandler`, just forward the cookies of the given `CookieHandler` by the following:

```
HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty('Cookie', MyCookieHandler.getCookiesOfHost(hostname));
```

It is also necessary to add the cookies from a `HttpUrlConnection` to `MyCookieHandler`. [Here](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html) is a useful link for doing it.